# Concatenate the term using substitute method via regex

Tags: python, regex, string, regex-group, python-re

> **Summary of problem:**
> I have written the generic regex to capture two groups from the sentence. Further I need to concatenate the 3rd term of 2nd group to the 1st group. I have used the word `and` in regex as partition to separate two groups of the sentence. For example:

> Input = 'Since, the genetic cells of SAC-1 and RbC-27 **synthesis** was not caused by WbC-2 of acnes in human face and animals **skin**.'

> Output = 'Since, the genetic cells of SAC-1 **synthesis** and RbC-27 **synthesis** was not caused by WbC-2 of acnes in human face **skin** and animals **skin**.'

> **What Regex I have tried:**

```py
import re
string_ = "Since, the genetic cells of SAC-1 and RbC-27 synthesis was not caused by WbC-2 of acnes in human face and animals skin." 
regex_pattern = re.compile(r"\b([A-Za-z]*-\d+\s*|[A-Za-z]+\s*)\s+(and\s*[A-Za-z]*-\d+\s*[A-Za-z]*|and\s*[A-Za-z]+\s*[A-Za-z]+)?")
print(regex_pattern.findall(string_))
print(regex_pattern.sub(lambda x: x.group(1) + x.group(2)[2], string_))
```

The regex is able to capture the groups but I'm getting error as `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` from the `substitute` method line. Any kind of suggestions or help to execute the above problem will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In terms of new questions, this is well written, good job! However, when you write "I'm getting error", that's a sign that you should include that error. Is the program exiting with an error? If so, please copy and paste the error message here. Or are you jsut getting the wrong output. If that is the case, try providing the output so users can try understanding what is going wrong without having to try the code first.

Comment: @Kraigolas Thanks for the suggestion. I have edited the question and included the error that I'm getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Split solution

While this is not a regex solution, this certainly works:

```
from string import punctuation

x = 'Since, the genetic cells of SAC-1 and RbC-27 synthesis was not caused by WbC-2 of acnes in human face and animals skin.'
x = x.split()
for idx, word in enumerate(x):
    if word == "and":
        # strip punctuation or we will get skin. instead of skin
        x[idx] = x[idx + 2].strip(punctuation) + " and"
print(' '.join(x))
```

Output is:

> Since, the genetic cells of SAC-1 synthesis and RbC-27 synthesis was not caused by WbC-2 of acnes in human face skin and animals skin.

This solution avoids inserting into the list directly as that would cause problems with indices as you iterate through. Instead, we replace the first "and" in the list with "synthesis and", and the second "and" with "skin and", and then rejoin the split string.

### Regex solution

If you insist upon a regex solution, I suggest using `re.findall` with a pattern containing a *single and* as this is more generalized for the problem:

```
from string import punctuation
import re
pattern = re.compile("(.*?)\sand\s(.*?)\s([^\s]+)")
result = ''.join([f"{match[0]} {match[2].strip(punctuation)} and {match[1]} {match[2]}" for match in pattern.findall(x)])
print(result)
```

> Since, the genetic cells of SAC-1 synthesis and RbC-27 synthesis was not caused by WbC-2 of acnes in human face skin and animals skin.

Once again we use `strip(punctuation)` because `skin.` is captured: we don't want to lose the punctuation at the *end* of the sentence, but we do want to lose it inside the sentence.

Here is our pattern:

```
(.*?)\sand\s(.*?)\s([^\s]+)
```

1. `(.*?)\s`: capture all content before the "and", including the space
2. `\s(.*?)\s`: capture the word immediately following the "and"
3. `([^\s]+)`: capture anything that is not a space up until the next space (ie. the second word after the "and"). This ensures we capture punctuation as well.

Comment: Your both the solutions are awesome and will work for generic cases too. Many thanks brother. Also within 30 mins I have learnt a few things from you.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to import `punctuation`, one single regular expression will work:

```py
import re
x = 'Since, the genetic cells of SAC-1 and RbC-27 synthesis was not caused by WbC-2 of acnes in human face and animals skin.'
pattern = re.compile(r"(.*?)\s+and\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\b([_\W]*)", re.DOTALL)
result = ''.join([f"{a} {c} and {b} {c}{d}" for a,b,c,d in pattern.findall(x)])
print(result)
```

**Results**: `Since, the genetic cells of SAC-1 synthesis and RbC-27 synthesis was not caused by WbC-2 of acnes in human face skin and animals skin.`

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##PY9Ba4NAEIXv/orBi7uJEdoeegolpMdAoRZyiKGM61i31VnZXWlE/O1WbellZg7vvfle2/vK8MM06aY11oOl4AZ7iFLNimLwFcEHMXmtQFFdOzAlpIfj7g6QC3jNj7v7R3A9z0KnHXyjAzYeFHaOCsh7OC@SxYWKyYFmqLoGGUpUtGYg6wbnYPelOYmCFr0nyzODpUSZptU1CRuKZPMkM7edHfMUWbqV/zsXl/fsfN3IMF5Mzy9vh9NJBpZcV/ulTJR8Gs3iUoYDjjCocX085Os9FGMIpbGAcR6ruFgQ/yCSUnOBdS1u8iqD1mr24jdVTtMP).

Use `re.DOTALL` to allow the dot to match line feed characters.
**Use `\b` word boundary at the end to strip puncutation and capture it into a separate group with `([_\W]*)`.**
Use `\s+` to trim any number of whitespace characters from the results.
`[^\s]` is the same as `\S`, make it shorter.

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/5QxkpB/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character (0 or more times (matching
                             the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  and                      'and'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \4:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [_\W]*                   any character of: '_', non-word
                             characters (all but a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \4
```

Comment: appreciated your solution. Your regex is working but in `.join` method need some minor changes since for instance the sentence `However, the gene of acne and non-acne patients was not affected by cancer.` the `.join` method terminates in between and doesn't consider the further part of the sentence in the output result.